# Javascript take number selected in a drop down and times by 1.09?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a drop down menu containing numbers,

```
<select>
  <option value="32">32</option>
  <option value="33">33</option>
  <option value="34">34</option>
  <option value="35">35</option>
</select>
```

and when a number is selected I want the value to be returned in a `<p id="returned-value"></p>`tag, but times by 1.09. How can I do that with javascript?

Comment: What was your attempt? SO is not a free code-writing service...

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = parseInt(document.getElementByTagName('select').value);
var newValue = value * 1.09;
document.getElementById('returned-value').innerHTML = newValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/62kbf7wf/1/)

As you can see in the fiddle, the (selected value * 1.9) is shown in the `<p>` as soon as a value is selected from the `<select>`. This is done using **onchange**. The onchange event occurs when the value of an element has been changed.

**HTML**

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<p id="demo">0</p>
```

**JS**

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x * 1.9;
}
```